# Hash every parameter with specific name in json

Tags: json, postgresql

I have jsonb:

```
{
    "param": 1,
    "code": "abc",
    "nested": [
        {
            "param": 11,
            "code": "abd",
            "nested": {}
        },
        {
            "param": 22,
            "code": "abe",
            "nested": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Count of elemets in "nested" array can be changed from case to case.

I need to hash every "code" parameter. At the result i need to obtain same jsonb, where every "code" = md5("code"). How can i do that?

I tried JSON_EACH but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected result based on that JSON

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing multiple values in json data is quite complex, because you need to break down the json data structure and then rebuild it manualy. In addition, when you want to replace several values inside the same json data, you will need to create first your own aggregate function based on `jsonb_set`.

Considering your jsonb data as a string may be much more simpler :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION code_md5 (x jsonb) RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS $$
SELECT string_agg(CASE WHEN a.ordinality = 1 THEN a ELSE c.md5_val || substr(a, length(b.val)+1) END, '"code": "') :: jsonb
  FROM regexp_split_to_table(x :: text, '"code": "') with ordinality AS a
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (regexp_match(a, '[^"]+'))[1] AS val) AS b
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT md5(b.val) AS md5_val) as c ;
$$ ;
```

The first step of this function split the json data using "code": " as a delimiter.
The second step looks for the value associated to the key "code".
The third step calculates the hash value.
The last step concatenates the differents parts all together while replacing the json values by the corresponding hash value.

The result is :

```
{
  "code": "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72",
  "param": 1,
  "nested": [
    {
      "code": "4911e516e5aa21d327512e0c8b197616",
      "param": 11,
      "nested": {}
    },
    {
      "code": "7888d65a43501d992cc38638b59964d6",
      "param": 22,
      "nested": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The case where double quotes are used inside the json value associated to the key "code" is not covered by this function (the result will be wrong).

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z64i87np)